# My python code doesn't work can you correct it?

Tags: python

When I run my code:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Debrise/draft.py
```

It tells this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Debrise/draft.py", line 91, in <module>
    res = d.query(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This are line 90 and 91

```
d = dataset("C:\\Debrise\\draft.csv")
res = d.query(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Are you passing any `args`?

Comment: Using `sys.argv[1]`, the script is expecting that you've provided another command line argument after the script's path -- `C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Debrise/draft.py {argv1}`.

Comment: import sys
SPLIT_CHAR = ";"    #split char (You can change this if you want to save in another csv format)

# This class handles a single material.
# For each material this class mantains composition information
class material:
 name = None    #Material name
 composition = None  #Material composition
 def __init__(self,composit

Comment: Thank you very much I'll try

Comment: d = dataset("C:\\Debrise\\draft.csv")-- C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Debrise/draft.py {argv1}
res = d.query(sys.argv[1])

Comment: I don't know how to write it

Comment: Jonathan Lonowski, I don't know any thing about python ... Where must I write the command line that you wrote: C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Debrise/draft.py {argv1}? In the next line or on the same line after d = dataset("C:\\Debrise\\draft.csv")?

Answer (score 2):

Look at your running attempt.

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Debrise/draft.py
```

Clearly, you aren't passing any argument here.

```
res = d.query(sys.argv[1])
```

In this line, you are trying to access an command line argument which isn't provided.

This is the reason behind the error.

Run the script like that:

```
python draft.py some_arg
```

Here, `some_arg` should be replaced by the argument you want to pass.